# Android OOM caused by drawable to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

Here is my code:

```
int[] image = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2};
```

And the getView:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView=LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(image[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Everything is fine. No OOM.

Then, I want to sample the drawable first:

```
public static Bitmap sampleImage(Context context, int resourceId, int sampleSize) {        
            Bitmap resizeBmp = null;
            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
            resizeBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, opts);

            return resizeBmp;
        }
```

And the new getView:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView=LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Bitmap item = BitmapUtil.sampleMaskInShelf(getApplicationContext(), image[position], 4);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(item);
        //      imageView.setBackgroundResource(image[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
```

The things happened. At first, the application does not crash. But the memory used is over 50MB, after I scroll up and down, it causes OOM.

The questions are:
1) Why sample the image will increase the memory used.
2) How to decrease the memory used,is there any other ways?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you are working with a ListView here?

In that case, you would be better served (and hopefully conserving a significant amount of memory) with a couple of steps:

1. You want to try to re-use the `convertView` whenever possible.  Many articles have been written on how to do this.  [Here is one](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/).
2. It looks like you only really have two different images (`image1` and `image2`).  It also seems like you are sampling the bitmap every time `getView()` is called.  You probably ought to pre-calculate the two sampled bitmaps, and just use those over and over again.

Comment: Also, why not just do the sampling of the two images in the constructor, and store field variables to the two different Bitmaps. Then, in the getView, just do 
    if(position % 2 == 0)
        //use bitmap for image1
    else
        //use bitmap for image2

Comment: @dennisdrew yeah, that was basically what I was suggesting in my point (2) above.

Comment: Yes, I was just clarifying for jjLin :)

Answer (score 2):

There are three excellent Android training articles which cover this exact issue:

1. [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
2. [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)
3. [Displaying Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html) (specifically with a GridView)

I might try reading over all three of those, understand what techniques they use and download the [sample application](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BitmapFun.zip) which encapsulates all of the training code into one example. I think in your case, pre-sampling the images down to their display size then using an [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html) might be more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector doesn't handle bitmap deallocation automatically for you, so any time you assign a bitmap directly to a variable you'll need to also call bitmap.recycle() when you're done with it. Failing to do so will result in a memory leak, which is what you've got. However, if you assign the bitmap to a drawable and then call bitmap.recycle(), and then try and use the drawable you'll get an exception because the drawable cannot access the recycled bitmap.

I was writing a ListView similar to what you've got, and what I ended up doing was calling bitmap.recycle on any bitmap that was more than ten slots above the current viewport, setting a flag on that ListView item to show its bitmap had been recycled, and then getting getView to re-load the bitmap if the user scrolled back up there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new view every time, you should try to reuse view like..

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null)  {   
        v=LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    } 
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(image[position]);

    return v;
}
```

and for more operation on OOM you should loo at below link.. 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Or You can use UniversalImage Loader Library to load image.. you can find its library from 
[UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

hope this help...